# What is merge conflict in iOS objective c when using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

*This might sound like duplicate question.* In all the place I searched, they said merge conflict will occur when more than one person uses storyboard. But no one explained **why, how, and when** it will exactly occur.

My question is: What is a merge conflict?

Second question is:  Why and when it will occur, and why it doesn't occur when we use programmatically?

Each person is going to work on different ViewControllers, so how this conflict occur.

Comment: Please try to limit each post to 1 question otherwise it becomes difficult to select a "correct" answer.

Comment: I think that the first and second Q can be put together. But the last one has a completely different topic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...  I have edited the question...

Comment: Storyboard is single XML file in real. No matter how many view controllers you make it's in single XML. You can right click storyboard and see the source from project navigator. If two people work on same file it will certainly result conflict. So to solve this user multiple storyboards.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that there is a little piece of text in the file. Let say, that there is a text "labeltext" and one developer changes it to "label" while you are changing it to "text". The source control system cannot know, which change is the "valid" one. It reports a merge conflict, so you and the other developer can decide, which version to take.

This can happen in code, too. But as a developer you are good in reading source code and likely bad in reading XIBs containing the storyboard. When you know, on which part of the software your colleague works, in many cases it is easy to decide, which version to use. If it is done in a XIB it is often impossible to you to know, even what the change is. You find yourself in the situation the version control system is: "Gmpf, what is the right version?"

Beside this, typically a storyboard is app global. You cannot say to your colleague: "Do not touch this file, I'll work on it today."